# Trouble when building LZ4 from source: "recipe for target 'test-fuzzer' failed"

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi, raspbian, dpkg

I am trying to install ROS (Robot Operating System) on Raspbian. There are some dependencies that I need which are unavailable for Raspbian, so I must build them from source. One of these is lz4. Here is a link to the guide I am using: [guide](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi)

I am running the command

```
apt-get source -b lz4
```

After 2 hours of running, it will eventually give the following error:

```
Starting LZ4 fuzzer (32-bits, )
Seed = 8544
Overflow tests : high address detected : Makefile:277: recipe for target 'test-fuzzer' failed
make[3]: *** [test-fuzzer] Killed
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/catkin_ws/external_src/lz4-0.0~r131/programs'
Makefile:98: recipe for target 'test' failed
make[2]: *** [test] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/catkin_ws/external_src/lz4-0.0~r131'
debian/rules:34: recipe for target 'override_dh_auto_test' failed
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/catkin_ws/external_src/lz4-0.0~r131'
debian/rules:26: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

I have also tried to use

```
apt-get source lz4
sudo apt-get build-dep lz4
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
```

I get the same error.

Does anybody know what might be causing this, or how I could proceed to find a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible this could be due to a lack of memory? I am using the orange pi which has limited memory.

Comment: This seems to be a relevant bug report:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=755170

It seems like it is just failing some test after building. Is there some way I can override the test? Sorry, I am not too familiar with this.

Comment: I'd guess the string `Overflow tests : high address detected :` isn't from `make` but from a test tool of the package (not properly terminated with line feed). Anyway, why don't you run this build in emulator which would be faster even with full instruction emulation?

Comment: I also ran into this issue while trying to install ROS on Raspbian following this guide: [http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi) Like user209877 I was able to build it successfully on a second try. I didn't run sudo apt-get install liblz4-dev before building the second time since it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the full flash card.  Make sure you expand the FS using the raspi-config utility.  The build process checks the compression of various sizes of files (10Mb up to 6Gb) so you'll need some free space. I have raspbian-lite on an 8Gb card on my A+ and had no trouble building lz4 although it took about 2-3 hrs.  You could also try add swap space.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same and already set up another question:
{
I am installing ROS on my RPi and when I try to install liblz4-dev with:

```
$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws/external_src
$ apt-get source -b lz4**
I get the following: 
...

Starting LZ4 fuzzer (32-bits, )
Seed = 3703
Overflow tests : high address detected : Makefile:277: recipe for target 'test-fuzzer' failed
make[3]: *** [test-fuzzer] Killed
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/external_src/lz4-0.0~r131/programs'
Makefile:98: recipe for target 'test' failed
make[2]: *** [test] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/external_src/lz4-0.0~r131'
debian/rules:47: recipe for target 'override_dh_auto_test' failed
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/external_src/lz4-0.0~r131'
debian/rules:33: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
Build command 'cd lz4-0.0~r131 && dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc' failed.
E: Child process failed

Everything worked fine including 3.2.1 Unavailable Dependencies > libconsole-bridge-dev:
```

Would be grateful for advice.}

But then it worked...I just ran: sudo apt-get install liblz4-dev before, but don't know if that was the problem.

Comment: Is this meant to be a new question or is this meant to be an answer? If it is meant to be an answer, can you more clearly state your proposed solution and remove the extraneous details?